# Decoding Blob method for the contentversion object through Rest Class

Tags: apex, salesforcemobilesdk-ios, apexrest

We are having pdf documents on Library objects under shared content.Now we are integrated through html for retriving the data.I Developed Rest class as like below.If i run this i am able to get pdf on browser but pdf was not decoding its giving "FAILED TO LOAD PDF CONTENT".It is an urgent requirement for me can any one suggest to achieve this?

```
@RestResource(urlMapping='/ContentDoc/*')
global class ContentDocController {
    @HttpGet
    global static void getBlob() {
    RestRequest req = RestContext.request;
    String Id= RestContext.request.params.get('ContentDocId') ;
    ContentVersion a = [SELECT ContentModifiedById,ContentDocumentId,FileExtension,FileType,ContentSize,ContentUrl,Id,VersionData,VersionNumber FROM ContentVersion where ContentDocumentId=:Id];
    RestResponse res = RestContext.response;
    res.addHeader('Content-Type',a.FileExtension);
   //String paramvalue =EncodingUtil.base64Encode(a.VersionData);
    String afterblob = EncodingUtil.base64Encode(a.VersionData);
    res.responseBody =EncodingUtil.base64Decode(afterblob); 
    } 
}
```

Thanksin advance

Comment: after removing this lin it should work String afterblob = EncodingUtil.base64Encode(a.VersionData);

Comment: Hi Himanshu thanks for your reply .I tried but Its giving variable not exist.Can u please guide me how we can modify it

Comment: How do we call this 'getBlob' from client side ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. we need to mention the 'application/pdf' on the rest class.Then it should load the pdf.

```
@RestResource(urlMapping='/ContentDoc/*')
   global class ContentDocController {
    @HttpGet
    global static void getBlob() {
    RestRequest req = RestContext.request;
    String Id= RestContext.request.params.get('ContentDocId') ;
    ContentVersion a = [SELECT ContentModifiedById,ContentDocumentId,FileExtension,FileType,ContentSize,ContentUrl,Id,VersionData,VersionNumber FROM ContentVersion where ContentDocumentId=:Id];
    RestResponse res = RestContext.response;
    res.addHeader('Content-Type',a.FileExtension);
     res.addHeader('Content-Type','application/pdf');
    String afterblob = EncodingUtil.base64Encode(a.VersionData);
    res.responseBody =EncodingUtil.base64Decode(afterblob); 
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The Versiondata field gives the base 64 encoded type data.In Your code you are encoding it again ,I think that's causing problem.Try Just decoding it.It will return you a blob and then try it.

Comment: I followed https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_restful_encodingUtil.htm  this link.Can u suggest me how To decode that      Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It might work for you

```
@RestResource(urlMapping='/ContentDoc/*')
global class ContentDocController {
    @HttpGet
    global static void getBlob() {
    RestRequest req = RestContext.request;
    String Id= RestContext.request.params.get('ContentDocId') ;
    ContentVersion a = [SELECT ContentModifiedById,ContentDocumentId,FileExtension,FileType,ContentSize,ContentUrl,Id,VersionData,VersionNumber FROM ContentVersion where ContentDocumentId=:Id];
    RestResponse res = RestContext.response;
    res.addHeader('Content-Type',a.FileExtension);
    res.responseBody =a.VersionData; 
    } 
}
```

Comment: HI Himanshu it is giving   Error: Compile Error: Method does not exist or incorrect signature: EncodingUtil.base64Decode(Blob) at line 10 column 23

Comment: @himanshu.  Also include in the where clause 'isLatest = true'

Comment: Thanks for giving reply.still it is giving error as [![enter image description here](http://i.stack.imgur.com/uMgpP.png)
Any other way please suggest me